# What is the use of a RLC circuit placed before a full bridge rectifier?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, resistors, inductor, passive-networks

While analysing a PCB, I realised that a RLC circuit was placed before the full bridge rectifier. I am wondering, what functional use does it have?

[image: The primary of the transformer, the capacitor near the side and the SMD resitor seem to form a RLC circuit]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBnPko.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The primary of the transformer, the capacitor near the side and the SMD resistor seem to form a RLC circuit.
I think it should have something to do with filtering. There is a toroidal transformer there with a 1:1 ratio which seems to output whatever voltage and current runs through the primary.

Comment: People are going to be much more receptive if you try and draw out a schematic of what you're seeing.

Comment: Upper blue device is a VDR (voltage dependent resistor), the transformer looks like a **common mode choke**, resistor probably for inrush current limiting and maybe also protection (like a fuse). So basically some filtering and protection for the incoming AC power. This is a very common component configuration. And next time: trace out the schematic.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie done

Comment: If the transformer in your schematic is the yellow choke in your picture then your interpretation of the circuit is incorrect. Rotate the transformer through 90 degrees and you'll probably get the correct circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more likely than not a common mode choke and it works to remove some forms of conducted interference produced by (or susceptible to) the equipment it is used in. The benefit is that you can meet EMC specifications.

[image]

Another example of its use: -

[image]

Comment: Can you give me some examples of noise types?

Comment: If you looked into how switch mode power supplies operate you'd find lots there to entertain you.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd like to ask, out of curiosity, what is the policy you follow when you answer questions? What "points" do you try to reach?

Comment: I just try and answer as best as I can without wasting peoples time with overly complex answers.

Comment: I see, but for people like me it's a pleasure to know more, idk. I'm not sure of one thing: why must noise be portrayed as common mode currents? Why can't it also be represented as differential mode currents?

Comment: Noise contamination is usually a bit of both but, differential noise tends not to produce the depth of radiation that common-mode noise produces because one field from one wire is cancelled by the opposite field from the other wire.

Comment: I see. From what you say, the choke has something like 50 % efficiency when it comes to removing noise, since  noise is both CM and DM.

Comment: If you have access to a simulation tool then you can easily model this up in minutes and start to get a better understanding. If you don't use a sim tool and you are interested in electronics then my best advise to you is get one and, after the sharp learning curve and appreciation of what a sim tool can deliver, you'll never look back. Micro-cap is the one I recommend and you can get the student edition for free.